# 'reset' table view cell's content

Tags: iphone, uitableview

my app has a bug, and i believe its because I'm not reseting the cells content. The apple docs say

> The table view’s data source implementation of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell.

Could someone please explain how to do this, or point me to a tutorial? Thank you in advance!

**My cellForRow**

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
     {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];

         addBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         addBtn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [addBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(220,10,25,55)];
         [addBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [addBtn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [addBtn setEnabled:YES];
         [cell addSubview:addBtn];

         subBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         subBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [subBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(260,10,25,55)];
         [subBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(subtractLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [subBtn setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [subBtn setEnabled:YES];
         [cell addSubview:subBtn];

     } 
    //cellText.hidden=!self.editing;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    cell.textLabel.text = [number objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];// <------ Is this line in the right place?
    cell.textLabel.text = @"1"; // <---- Is this line in the right place? 


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your routine looks OK.  Is "number" an array of NSString *? if not, that's probably where you're dying.  You need to put an NSString object in the cell.textLabel.text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple.  You provide the call cellForRowAtIndexPath in your code.  In it, you either provide a brand new cell, or you reuse a cell that the OS has chucked into memory.  Basically, you code looks like this:

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
[[cell textLabel] setText:[pickerData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
 cell.accessoryType = (indexPath.row == currentValueOfIndex ) ? 
    UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


return cell;
```

The part under the comment // Configure the cell is where you have to reset your cells content.  Since it can either be a new cell, or a recycled cell, it will either have no information, or the information from another cell where it was recycled from.  In both cases, you provide the cell's text and accessories and anything else you want to use each time the cell is called.  Basically, it's a callback to you to provide a cell, either a brand new one, or a recycled one, and you have to stuff the right info for the cell it's going to be (based on the index path).  Hope I made this clear enough.

Comment: oh, okay i think i understood you. If i have the code to set the text of the cell under the // comment, then it will be added to the new cell if its in the same indexPath? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should think of it this way: cellForRowAtIndexPath is a method you supply that gives cells on request to the list.  You either create a brand new cell (cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]...) or you reuse a cell that has previously been scrolled off the list when the user scrolls the list (the list keeps track of these, and you get one with dequeueReusableCell...).  In both cases, you plug in the correct text of the cell for the index path that been requested. In my example, I just used some text from a pickerData array, but any NSString * will do.  I also am using the checkmark accessory, too

Comment: @owenHarnett alright, if i want the cells text to be brand new each time, put it below the `if` statement, right? Also, if i alter the cells `textLabel`, and i store the new label's text in an array, where should i set the cell's text now? because i cant do it under the `if` statement, or can i? Please help me! I am so confused! i have already read the docs and im still sort of confused! ill post my `cellForRow` method in my question above if you could please take a look and see if its right? THank you very much!!

Comment: Read my previous post.  Your cellForRow method supplies cells to the list.  The list tells you what indexPath to use, and you stuff the data appropriate for that indexPath (usually just the indexPath.row, unless you use a grouped list).   1) you write the cellForRow method that will provide a properly filled out cell when the list calls for it.  2) you usually never call cellForRow, your list does! 3) When you provide the cell, you first check to see if there are any other ones that you can reuse. 4) if you don't reuse, create new. 5) stuff the value for that row in the cell 6) return the cell

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding views programmatically to the cell, you should do the following for cleaning  them:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellID";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];        
    }

    for (UIView * v in cell.contentView.subviews) {        
        [v removeFromSuperview]
    }

    //Configure your cell

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: how come you have the `removeFromSuperView` code in the `if` statement? Wouldnt this just remove the view before they are even shown?

Answer (score 1):

See the comments in the code below...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellID";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
        // this is where you want to configure your generic cell
        // for example, if EVERY cell needs to have a disclosure indicator, you could do
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryTypeDisclosurseIndicator;    
    }

    // this is where you want to put code that would or could be unique to a cell
    // for example, if you wanted to put the row number you could do:
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
    // you would put this here and not in the above if statement because the value of the textLabel changes for different cells

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: right, i understand where to put the code at, i just am not sure what statement/code to put to 'reset' the content of the cell and thank you for the help!!